# A inequality of area in Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}z^n$ is a univalent holomorphic function in$B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$,How to prove that$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|a_{n}|^2\leq1.$$

Comment: I think we can let $g(z)=f(z)-\frac{1}{z}$,then $g(z)$ is a holomorphic function in $B(0,1)$,and the area of $g(B(0,1))$ is$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|a_{n}|^2$. But I would not prove the inequality.

Comment: This is the so-called Area theorem, proved in many books on complex analysis. For example, it is Theorem 14.13 in Rudin's Real and complex analysis.